# how to create a template specialization for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I created a general templated class, as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class sc_in_upf : public sc_channel
{
.
.
.
};
```

after that, i needed a specialization for a specific data type, then i created it:

```
template<>
class sc_in_upf <sc_dt::sc_logic> : public sc_channel
{

.
.
.
};
```

until here, everything was working as expected, but now I need to create another specialization for a templated data type ( `sc_lv<int U>` ), and I don't know how to do it:

I tried:

```
template<>
class sc_in_upf <sc_dt::sc_lv<int U>> : public sc_channel
{

.
.
.
};
```

but the compiler fails due to:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
 class sc_in_upf < sc_dt::sc_lv<int V>> : public sc_channel
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: `template <int U> class sc_in_ufp<sc_dt::sc_lv<U>> : ...`

Comment: thanks a lot, i followed your example and it is now working!